# Api call not working in alamofire but working in postman

Tags: swift, alamofire, postman

[image]I have an API Call which is working using postman but when same data is given in alamofire it is not working. Please help me. I spent around 1 day fixing it.

```
        let parameters = [
        "paymenttype":"debitcard",
        "coupon":"",
        "products":[["pid":"72","qnty":"1"],["pid":"4","qnty":"1"],["pid":"3","qnty":"1"]],
        "grandtotal":"71499.52",
        "discount":"",
        "itemtotalval":"69417.0",
        "cgst":"1041.26",
        "comment":"sss",
        "sgst":"1041.26",
        "billingaddress":[["bfname":"debdeep nandy","bmobilenumber":"9875463215","bpincode":"823691" , "baddress":"kolkata","bcity":"kolkata","bstate":"West Bengal","bcountry":"india","bemail":"dev@gmail.com"]],
        "shippingaddress":[["sfname":"debdeep nandy","smobilenumber":"9875463215","spincode":"823691","saddress":"kolkata","scity":"kolkata","sstate":"West Bengal","scountry":"india","semail":"india"]],
        "user_id":1
        ] as [String : AnyObject]
    Alamofire.request(
        URL(string:"http://jarsservices.com/pccj-app/apiv1/place_order")!,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters)
        .validate()
        .responseString { (response) -> Void in
           
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                print("Error while sending data: \(response.result.error)")
                return
            }

            if let value = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   // self.activityView.stopAnimating()

                    if value["status"] as! Int == 1 {
                        self.view.makeToast("Thank you! Your feedback is recorded in server.")
                    }
                    else {
                        self.view.makeToast(value["msg"] as? String)
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                print("Malformed data received from fetchAllRooms service")
                return
            }


    }
```

There is no authentication in headers. please help me out.

I have added the image from postman that is working.

Comment: Can u share with us the postman so we can see how can we help u out ?

Comment: @AaoIi what all I have to share.

Comment: API: http://jarsservices.com/pccj-app/apiv1/place_order

Comment: i want to see how its being sent from your postman that your doing wrong in here, just export it as single url not the whole collection as url.

Comment: Sir I am not getting what you are telling, I am new to postman so I added the postman screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Out this code,

Add this extension

```
extension Array where Element: Codable {

    public var toData: Data {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            return try encoder.encode(self)
        }
        catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    public var toJson: String? {
        return toData.toJson
    }
}

extension Data {
    //  Convert NSData to String
    public var toJson : String? {
        return String(data: self, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
}
```

You web API `Parameters` like

```
let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "paymenttype":"debitcard",
        "coupon":"",
        "products":[["pid":"72","qnty":"1"],["pid":"4","qnty":"1"],["pid":"3","qnty":"1"]].toJson ?? "[]",
        "grandtotal":"71499.52",
        "discount":"",
        "itemtotalval":"69417.0",
        "cgst":"1041.26",
        "comment":"sss",
        "sgst":"1041.26",
        "billingaddress":[["bfname":"debdeep nandy","bmobilenumber":"9875463215","bpincode":"823691" , "baddress":"kolkata","bcity":"kolkata","bstate":"West Bengal","bcountry":"india","bemail":"dev@gmail.com"]].toJson ?? "[]",
        "shippingaddress":[["sfname":"debdeep nandy","smobilenumber":"9875463215","spincode":"823691","saddress":"kolkata","scity":"kolkata","sstate":"West Bengal","scountry":"india","semail":"india"]].toJson ?? "[]",
        "user_id":1
        ]
```

And Your else Part is

```
else {
    print("Malformed data received from fetchAllRooms service")
    debugPrint(String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)) 
    //Print out our data 
    return
}
```

[image]

**Note:** in `Alamofire` parameter Pass `Array` or `Dictionary` value using JSON string format then this is worked.

Comment: Value of type 'Data' has no member 'toJson'

Comment: You have replace you coding else part

Comment: Thanks dude you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

**Try out with this method:**

```
func hitPostServiceJsonForm(_ params:Dictionary<String,Any>,unReachable:(() -> Void),handler:@escaping ((Dictionary<String,Any>?) -> Void)) {


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: BASE_URL)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)

        print_debug(BASE_URL)
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
            SwiftLoader.hide()
            //print_debug("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            //print_debug("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print_debug("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                    print_debug("Json Response: \(jsonDict)") // serialized json response
                    handler(jsonDict)
                }
                else{
                    handler(nil)
                }
                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Server Response: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                handler(nil)
                print_debug(error)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}))
  ▿ failure : AFError
    ▿ responseSerializationFailed : ResponseSerializationFailureReason

Comment: It seems like your server return HTML 
Enable the two more prints so that you will get actual problem.

Comment: I know that the server is returning an html. But I can't debug it since its a client server. I am asking if same data is working in postman then how it is not working using alamofire.

Comment: Have you enable these two?:

//print_debug("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            //print_debug("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")

Comment: sir in the html it is returning an error telling some data is missing. But I am sending all the data.

Comment: Try to pass user id in string.

Comment: I have tried your param adding in postman and it gives me error in postman as well

Comment: <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
            <p>Error Number: 1048</p>
            <p>Column 'name' cannot be null</p>